# Building JSON array dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm trying to pass the price for the first product in the cart in the form of an array.

The code below passes both the values as one variable and that's not what I want - I want an array to be built for each item price in the cart.

```
<script>

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({

  'firstItemUnitPrice': '<?php
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product = $values['data']->post;
        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);  

        echo $price;
    }; 
?>'    
});

</script>
```

The code above outputs:

firstItemunitprice: 1144

This is because there are two products in cart, one worth $11 and one $44.

I know how to separate them but I want them to be added as an array. Help?

Comment: Create a regular `array` and then use `json_encode()` on it

Comment: you don't "build json arrays". you build a NATIVE array, in whatever language you're working with. then ENCODE that array into json.

Answer (score 2):

So I understand that you want something like this:

`dataLayer = [{firstItemUnitPrice:11}, {firstItemUnitPrice:44}]`

To do this the best option is to create the array first in `PHP` and after that just echo the `json_encode` of that array.

So you can create the array like this:

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $dataLayer = [];
    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
         $_product = $values['data']->post;
         $dataLayer[] = [
              'firstItemUnitPrice' => get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true)
         ];

     }; 
?>
```

And after that echo the `json_encode` to dataLayer in `javascript` like this:

```
<script>

   window.dataLayer = '<?php echo json_encode($dataLayer); ?>';

</script>
```

I hope this is what you want.